# Creating shortcut to a network location on desktop

Tags: networking, shortcuts

I am currently trying to make a desktop shortcut pointing to a network location.

I believe there's a way to do this and that I am probably missing something simple.

Can anyone able to point me in the right direction? I am trying to create a short cut pointing to: \192.168.1.90

Comment: pointing in browser or nautilus???

Comment: pointing in nautilus if possible

Comment: i have posted answer, please say what you get @user12622

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say your server is an sftp server of the url `ftp://myserver.com` and your username there is `myuser` (works the same way for a regular ftp server or samba). You can open it with your regular **nautilus** file manager using `nautilus ftp://myuser@myserver.com &`.

The proceeding to do so in a `.desktop` file is basically as in [天使の](https://askubuntu.com/users/47044/)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170768/17789). You create a *.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Network(myserver)
Comment=Open ip in Nautilus
Exec=nautilus nautilus ftp://myuser@myserver.com
Icon=network
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Keywords=Network;myserver;
Name[en_US]=blubb
```

When you first connect to that server, you will be asked for a Password. Type in your password and click "Remember forever" in the password dialog.

Comment: Thank you, this has done the trick, just chose to use SMB instead of FTP. Thanks again

Comment: Its works but I had to add: `chmod +x` to the file created so Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't raise a warning when truing to open the link.

Answer (score 2):

Open gedit text editor and 
copy the below text and paste it into a new file. Then save the file giving name `Network(192.168.1.90).desktop` and exit gedit. Then from terminal, run this command `chmod +x Network(192.168.1.90).desktop`(to make it executable)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Network(192.168.1.90)
Comment=Open ip in Nautilus 
Exec=nautilus-connect-server \\192.168.1.90
Icon=network
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;
X-GNOME-Keywords=Network;192.168.1.90;
```

Then double clicking the icon, will execute the file. Provide feedback, if it doesn't work.

---

If you want to remember configuration use [Filezilla[image: 3]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/filezilla/) instead of **Nuatilus**
[image: download]

[image: configuration]

give all configuration, and site name rename for example: `site_one`
after that just change in **.desktop** file

```
Exec=filezilla -c site_name
```

and save that file

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. This allows me to connect up to the server, however it doesn't remember the details. It prompts me to enter the details each time. Is there a way to make it remember these?

Comment: @user12622 you can use filezila instead of nautilus, it can remember your config

Comment: @con-f-use can you give an example?

Comment: Stand by, I will formulate an answer.

Comment: @天使の I am looking to integrate into nautilus for ease to be honest. I am trying to get everyone in the house switched over to Ubuntu, but the server is heavily used, and everyone requires easy access.

Comment: @user12622 don't know how to make nautilus remember, but i think file zilla is easy too, it is very user friendly :D

Comment: @天使の no worries, thank you for trying. Unfortunately I am the only computer literate user here really, they are getting on ok with Ubuntu this far, but I just think FTP isn't the best option for this. I need to get a "double click" approach for them and opening files off the server.

Comment: @hingev my ubuntu user is "Ubuntu" while the SMB server user is "Operator". When I click a shortcut made as you hinted, the form is already filled with "Ubuntu" as user name, so with my local user name: do you know if is possible to save "Operator" in the shortcut? Thank you