# Add Network Location to Unity Bar

Tags: unity, samba, 16.04

I have a NAS device on my network. I can access the device by clicking the Network button on the left sidebar of Nautilus and selecting the device and share folder from there. I can also bookmark the share folder and access it directly from the Unity bar by right clicking the Nautilus icon and clicking the share.

That's all well and good, but I would like the network share to appear in the Unity bar as an icon, just like physically connected (HDDs, USB drives, CD/DVDs, etc.) devices do. Is there any way to do this on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: May be possible by adding .desktop file to launcher. May i ask for details on how you bookmark it ? I don't have access to network shares on my private network , so I'll need something to work with

Comment: @Serg that could work, yeah. Whenever I go into a share on the NAS, a new button for that share is created on the left sidebar, in line with local drives. I just right click that button and click "Add Bookmark." I can also bookmark local drives that same way, but unlike network locations, they appear on the Unity bar, so there's no real reason to bookmark them.

Comment: here's a couple solutions I've dug up: http://askubuntu.com/q/170766/295286  and http://askubuntu.com/q/620441/295286  Essentially the same thing as I was proposing. The second link has accepted answer by one of our resident python experts , Jacob Vlijm .  Although I don't agree with his statement that it's not-advisable to add `.desktop` file to launcher ( because it works, and that's all that matters in my opinion), his app for quicklists is quite useful even beyond the scope of this question, so  . . . check it out - either might work for you